# New Relic on heroku with nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, newrelic

How install New Relic on Heroku cedar stack with Node.js?

Official documentation comming soon...

Heroku tutorials is withiout nodejs.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic

Answer (score 3):

New Relic for Node.js is in beta now: https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/

If you want to be notified of when it's released, you can do that here: http://try.newrelic.com/nodejs

Answer (score 2):

New Relic does not have official support for Node.js yet. You can use a 3rd party Heroku add-on like [Nodetime](https://addons.heroku.com/nodetime) to track down issues. It's currently in beta, and free.

Answer (score 2):

New Relic does not currently have official support for Node.js. I have used [Nodefly](http://apm.nodefly.com/) for some profiling needs. It's not completely full featured but their working on it all the time to make it better. It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Now New Relic officially supports Node.js.

http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/10/24/node-joins-new-relic-family/